# Backbutton overwrite in JSP

Tags: jsp

I need to implement a functionality in my project where there are two jsps Jsp1 and jsp2. Request goes to jsp2 by java class which sets some cookie based on various conditions. When user is on jsp2 and he clicks on Browser back button, control should remain on Jsp2 only.

I tried setting cookie for this purpose, but that is creating lots of problem so I am not going with that approach.

Please suggest some ideas to achieve this functionality.

Comment: You can't control Browser buttons ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to disable the 'back' button when a user is on JSP2? What's the relevance of JSP1 to this question?

Comment: jsp1 is login.jsp and jsp2 is intermediate jsp. So once user comes to intermediate jsp..he should not be allowed to go to login.jsp by using browser back button.